# Is there a way to scale radio buttons or checkboxes for MFC CDialog?

Tags: c++, checkbox, mfc, radio-button, cdialog

We scale the controls in the dialog based on a current "zoom" font size.  Works great for text, edit controls, group boxes.

However, the physical radio button circle and checkbox squares are all the same/original "100%" size.

[image: Example 100%/225%/65% Scale]

Other than writing our own controls, is there a way to scale the standard radio button or checkbox graphics?

Comment: When you change the DPI settings of your desktop, Windows adjusts the system fonts sizes.  This affects most applications' Dialog boxes (the infamous "dialog units") AND the scaling of checkboxes and radio buttons within the dialog boxes.  Obviously, something is being done by Windows that I would like to similarly do programmatically in my code.  Any ideas???